# How can I dispatch a custom event from a Web Component and catch it in a React Functional Component and use it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component

What could I be doing wrong? I am dispatching a custom event called "select-date" from a custom web component date picker and am not sure whether it's reaching the React functional component that consumes it. The issue is that it's not logging as expected when I test it. Find my code below:

**What I have tried and where I have consulted includes ChartGPT, a few other tutorials related to this and other related issues here Stackoverflow, but at least to no avail yet!**

```
import { Calendar, Day } from ".";

class DatePicker extends HTMLElement {
  
  constructor() {
     super();

     //...
  }

   attributeChangedCallback(name: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any) {
    //...
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.mounted = true;

    //...
  }
  
  emitSelectDateEvent(dateTile: HTMLButtonElement) {
    if (parseInt(dateTile.innerHTML) === this.date.date) {
      const event = new CustomEvent("select-date", {
        detail: this.date,
      });
      this.dispatchEvent(event);
      // event tested and emitting event well.
      console.log(event);
    }
  }

  selectDay(dateTile: HTMLButtonElement, day: any) {
    //.... Other code here
    this.emitSelectDateEvent(dateTile);
  }

  
  updateMonthDays() {

    this.getMonthDaysGrid().forEach((day: any) => {
      const newDateTile = document.createElement("button");
      newDateTile.textContent = day.date;
      newDateTile.addEventListener("click", () =>
        this.selectDay(newDateTile, day)
      ); 
    });
  }

}
```

And the FormField component consuming the date picker web component below:

```
import {
  ChangeEventHandler,
  DOMAttributes,
  HTMLInputTypeAttribute,
  MutableRefObject,
  useEffect,
} from "react";
import { Calendar, DatePicker } from "../date-picker";
import Card from "../cards/Card";

/** A Web Component Custom DatePicker */
type CustomElement<T> = Partial<T & DOMAttributes<T> & { children: any }>;

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      ["date-picker"]: CustomElement<DatePicker>;
    }
  }
}

type FormFieldProps = {
  cols?: number;
  element: string;
  fieldRef: MutableRefObject<any>;
  fileName?: any;
  handleInputClick?: () => void | undefined;
  icon: any;
  id: string;
  label?: string;
  labelRef: MutableRefObject<any>;
  name: string;
  rows?: number;
  step: string[];
  type?: HTMLInputTypeAttribute;
  value?: string;
  onInputChange?: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined;
  onTextAreaChange?: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined;
};

const FormField = ({
  element,
  fieldRef,
  handleInputClick,
  id,
  name,
  onInputChange,
  type,
  value,
}: FormFieldProps) => {
    

  useEffect(() => {
    const datePicker = document.querySelector("date-picker");
    datePicker?.addEventListener("select-date", handleSelectDate);

    console.log(datePicker); // Tested and logged the date picker.

    return () => {
      datePicker?.removeEventListener("select-date", handleSelectDate);
      console.log("Dismounted Custom Event Listener..."); 
    };
  }, []);

  const handleSelectDate = (event: CustomEventInit): void => {
    // NOT BEING REACHED!!
    console.log(
      "select-date event received in Calendar component with date:",
      event.detail
    );
    // setSelectedDate(selectedDate); 
    // ...rest of the code
  };

  const cal = new Calendar();
  // console.log(cal.getPreviousMonth());

  /**
   * Main return call in switch statement */
  switch (element) {
    case "input":
      return (
        <Card
          className={
            name === "art"
              ? "art-wrapper input-wrapper"
              : name === "song"
              ? "input-wrapper song-wrapper"
              : name === "submit"
              ? "input-wrapper submit-wrapper"
              : "input-wrapper"
          }
          handleClick={handleClick}
          name={name}
          renderFileName={renderFileName}
        >
          <label
            className={
              name === "art"
                ? "song-art-label"
                : name === "song"
                ? "track-label"
                : undefined
            }
            htmlFor={id}
          >
            
            <input
              id={id}
              hidden={name === "art" ? true : name === "song" ? true : false}
              name={name}
              onBlur={handleFocusBlur}
              onChange={
                name === "art" || name === "song"
                  ? handleFieldChange
                  : onInputChange
              }
              onClick={name === "releaseYear" ? handleInputClick : undefined}
              onFocus={handleFocusBlur}
              ref={fieldRef}
              type={type}
              value={value}
            />
            

            {name === "releaseYear" && (
              <date-picker
                format={"MMM DD (DDD), YYYY"}
                date={"01-01-2023"}
                position={"top"}
                visible
              ></date-picker>
            )}
          </label>
        </Card>
      );
    case "textarea":
      return (
        <label className="" htmlFor={id}>
          {/** unrelated code */}          
        </label>
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export default FormField;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, and so I want to give the solution so as to help anybody who might run into a similar issue. 
So the drill is that the custom web component API should mount at the same time as the component consuming it; otherwise, the custom event that is dispatched from the web component (DatePicker in my case with a custom selector `<date-picker>`) will be missed. 
The issue is that my consumer component `FormField.tsx` is a reusable component, and by the time `<date-picker>` is being mounted, the underlying `useEffect()` method has already fired, hence we missed attaching the event listener. So here below is the code that has the fix, where I observed the changing variable per render of this `FormField.tsx` component, which is `name` in this case, and made it the specific array dependency, and that then attached the event listener appropriately.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (name !== "releaseYear") {
      return;
    }

    console.log("date picker component mounted");

    const datePicker = document.querySelector("date-picker");
    datePicker?.addEventListener("select-date", handleSelectDate);

    return () => {
      datePicker?.removeEventListener("select-date", handleSelectDate);
      console.log("Dismounted Custom Event Listener...");
    };
  }, [name]);
```